# how to suppress directory names in tar archived files?

Tags: linux, unix, tar

Suppose I have the following directories and files

```
inc:
inc/foo.h
inc/bar.h
inc/more.h
src:
src/foo.cc
src/bar.cc
src/more.cc
```

and I want to generate a tape archive using `tar` which contains some of those files (all with `foo` or `bar` in their name), but as if they are all in one single directory. Thus, after unpacking *via `tar -xf archive.tar`* my archive somewhere, I have

```
somewhere/foo.h
somewhere/bar.h
somewhere/foo.cc
somewhere/bar.cc
```

Can I do that just with tar and without moving/copying my files? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using GNU `tar` and `tar --help`:

> File name transformations:
>
> - `--strip-components=NUMBER`
>   strip NUMBER leading components from file names on extraction
> - `--transform=EXPRESSION`, `--xform=EXPRESSION`
>   use sed replace EXPRESSION to transform file names

On the face of it, therefore, you use it at extract time:

```
tar -xf filename.tar --strip-components=1 -C somewhere
```

The `-C somewhere` changes directory to `somewhere` before extracting files.

---

Since you know about the `--strip-components` option but it doesn't meet your requirements, the next option to try is `--transform`.  Since you want to remove all leading components of the path, then the expression can be quite simple:

```
tar -cf filename.tar --transform='s%.*/%%' .
```

This seems to work; I tested it using:

```
$ mkdir junk
$ cd junk
$ mkdir inc src
$ for file in inc/foo.h inc/bar.h inc/more.h src/foo.cc src/bar.cc more.cc; do cp ../makefile $file; done
$ tar -cf - --transform='s%.*/%%' . | tar -tvf -
drwxr-x--- jleffler/eng      0 2014-05-06 10:00 ./
-rw-r----- jleffler/eng   1183 2014-05-06 10:00 more.cc
drwxr-x--- jleffler/eng      0 2014-05-06 10:00 inc/
-rw-r----- jleffler/eng   1183 2014-05-06 10:00 more.h
-rw-r----- jleffler/eng   1183 2014-05-06 10:00 bar.h
-rw-r----- jleffler/eng   1183 2014-05-06 10:00 foo.h
drwxr-x--- jleffler/eng      0 2014-05-06 10:00 src/
-rw-r----- jleffler/eng   1183 2014-05-06 10:00 bar.cc
-rw-r----- jleffler/eng   1183 2014-05-06 10:00 foo.cc
$
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer... However, I should have been clearer in my question: I don't want to change the unpack command. (I found the `--strip-components` flag too, but it doesn't seem to help when archiving).

Comment: Yup; you should certainly have included that information in the question.  Have you tried the `--transform=` option; it is not clearly marked 'extraction'?

Comment: I have added that info to the question now. No, I havn't tried the `--transform=`, essentially because I'm not sufficiently familiar with `sed`. If you could give me a `sed` expression that would do it that would be great!

Comment: The other question would be 'why are you changing the layout'?  It is generally better to keep the source in the same directory structure so that the same makefile (or the configuration files for any other build tool) can be used.

Comment: Thanks. Re your *other question*: Yes, I know. I only want to extract one header and one source file from some directory structure without having the directory paths of them in the archive. Compilation is fine, since the #include directive doesn't contain any path.